# Thermal Properties of Superhydrophobic Surfaces

Tags: thermodynamics

I am carrying out a trial and have found that a heating pipe will have a higher surface temperature when treated with a superhydrophobic coating.

Does anyone know why this is? [image: Coating on the right hand side of the pipe]

[image: Higher surface temperature on the coated part of the pipe]

Comment: Interesting. What kind of hydrophobic coating are you using?

Comment: Its in the form of an aerosol.

Comment: Ok, but do you know the chemical composition?

Comment: Acetone, propane, butane and a silicone derived product (specific details unknown)

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the different (lower) heat radiation emission properties of the superhydrophobic coating, so that the coated pipe surface gets hotter. Try any other coatings of comparable thickness for comparison to see how the temperature varies between them. I would suspect that the effect has nothing to do with the superhydrophobicity.